# If condition break

Tags: javascript

```
if(Condition) {

} 

if(condition) {

}

if(condition) { 

} else { 

}
```

If the first condition fails, it should break instead of executing the last `if/else` conditon

Comment: Have you tried a switch-case scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erm, use nested if statements? I'm not entirely sure what you want to do with the result of the second condition, but here's what it looks like if the first condition isn't met:

```
if (condition1) {
  // First condition succeeds

  // Assuming you want to execute this either way
  if (condition2) {
  }

  // Only execute if first condition succeeds
  if (condition3) {
  } else {
  }
} else {
  // First condition fails

  // Assuming you want to execute this either way; ignore otherwise
  if (condition2) {
  }
}
```

Note also that if you want to return a value from a function, you can use something like `if (!condition1) return false;`.

As for whether the above is what you're looking for: this question is mad ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (condition1) { 
   if (condition2) {
   }

   if (condition3) {
   }
   else {
   }
}
```

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

What type are we working with here? What is Condition?

If you have more than 2 possible values for `Condition` I recommend that you use Switch - Case

```
switch (Condition)
{
    case 'Case1' :
        // Insert logic here
        break;
    case 'Case2' :
        // Insert logic here
        break;
    case 'Case3' :
        // Insert logic here
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me, you could just do the following:

```
if(Conditon) {
  // code
} else if(Condition) {
  // code
} else if(Condition) {
  // code
} else {
  // code
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

all above named solutions are functionally correct. i think the most popular is this one:

```
if(Conditon1) {
  // code
} else if(Condition2) {
  // code
} else if(Condition3) {
  // code
} else {
  // code
}
```

If you ask some Design-Pattern and Refactoring fans, you will maybe get this one:

```
if(Conditon1) {
  return doSomething();
} 

if(Condition2) {
  return doSomething2();
} 

if(Condition3) {
  return doSomething3();
}
```

it depends on your programming-style and what kind of books you've read :)

Comment: "Most popular" is not the same as "what the OP asked for".